# How to perform delete on matching rows with id copied from another using dblink Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

I am using dblink to copy data from one database to another using following code:

```
    INSERT INTO testtable select * from 
    dblink('host=localhost
            user=postgres
            password=root
            dbname=postgres', 'select * from testtable') as testtable(
            id bigint,
            name character varying
    );
```

Now I want to delete rows from parent table which were copied using dblink. How to do it?

Comment: Did you consider using foreign tables? But more often then not, using multiple databases is the wrong approach in Postgres to begin with. If you just want to separate data, schemas might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use of dblink doesn't really change anything here.  If you want to do it in one statement, you could combine RETURNING, a CTE, and DELETE...USING, same as if you were selecting from a local table.

```
WITH T as (
    INSERT INTO testtable select * from 
    dblink('host=localhost
            user=postgres
            password=root
            dbname=postgres', 'select * from testtable') as testtable(
            id bigint,
            name character varying
    ) 
    RETURNING *
)
DELETE from foo USING t where foo.id=t.id
```

There are other ways you could formulate it as well.